How to get rid of dots for space characters (buffer-display-table)
I'm seeing space characters in typescript-tsx-mode (tree-sitter, emacs 29) rendered as the "middle dot" unicode character: ·.  The dots show up even when the space characters are at the start of a normal line that has no trailing whitespace.
buffer-display-table has a [183] (middle dot) at the index for character 32 (space).  Clearly the latter is the immediate cause.  If I (setq buffer-display-table nil), the dots go away.  However, every time I open a new TSX file, the dots come back.
whitespace-mode and global-whitespace-mode are disabled at the point when I open the file, so it seems unrelated to those.  Having turned off a lot of other minor modes, describe-mode now says this, but I still have the dots displayed:
Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Evil-Local Font-Lock
My last resort is to start from zero and slowly biscect adding configuration back, but that's a slow and tiresome process.
How can I get rid of the dots permanently, so I don't have to set the variable every time I open a file?  I'd be happy even with some hack that turns it off in some "late" hook in the file opening process!

This seems to work, so I suspect lsp-mode is at fault (defun fix-typescript-whitespace () (setq buffer-display-table nil)) (add-hook 'lsp-ts-ls-after-open-hook 'fix-typescript-whitespace)
I wonder what it's doing and how I can ask it to stop?

Add your comment to the question, if it's relevant.

I googled a bit looking for the source code using "typescript-tsx-mode", but couldn't find it.  To the extent that the O.P. would like to broaden the base of forum participants who might be interested in working on this particular issue, it would be helpful to provide a link to the source code.

@Drew I guess I see my comment as a provisional answer more than an extension to the question.  A bad enough answer that maybe I should wait in case a better one shows up! (which I think the site makes me do anyway maybe)

@lawlist I think it's somehow provided by typescript-ts-mode.el? - which is part of emacs https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/typescript-ts-mode.el
